# Making an HTML string from a React component in background, how to use the string by dangerouslySetInnerHTML in another React component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mathjax

I'm trying to render LaTeX strings in a React project.
Although I use the `react-mathjax` React components, I want to get an HTML string made from the LaTeX strings in order to concatenate it and the other strings and set it by dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

### My current code I tried

Sample cod [here](https://github.com/Nyoho/test-react-project/blob/component2string/src/components/tex.jsx)

1. LaTeX strings are given as strings
2. Make an empty DOM `aDom` by `document.createElement('span')` (in background. not in the document DOM tree.)
3. Render a LaTeX string by `ReactDOM.render` into `aDom`
4. After rendering, get a string by `aDom.innerHTML` or `.outerHTML`

### Problem

The value of `aDom.innerHTML` (or `.outerHTML`) is `"<span><span data-reactroot=\"\"></span></span>"` (almost empty)
although `aDom` has a perfect tree that MathJax generated.

Briefly,

1. `aDom`:
2. `aDom.outerHTML`:

[image]

### Question

How can I get the 'correct' HTML string from `aDom` above?

Answer (score 98):

This seems to work just fine if you want to render any component to a HTML string:

```
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from 'react-dom/server'

function componentToString() {
  return renderToStaticMarkup(<MyAwesomeComponent some="props" or="whatever" />)
}
```

Comment: (Sorry to be late.) I rewrote it with `renderToString` in renderToString branch: https://github.com/NyohoSampleCodes/test-react-project/blob/renderToString/src/components/tex.js#L20 But it seems to be still empty.

Comment: Is a `function` missing? And maybe with another name, it's a but confusing to reuse the imported one.

Comment: Loved it!! Too useful for properties that needs an html string. Now create a component, then stringify to html. Beautiful :)

Answer (score 9):

From what I see, you are getting what you'd expect to get.

Given a root element (`aDom` in your case), ReactDOM will render it's root component inside this element, and this component's element will have the attribute `data-reactroot`.

So what you are seeing is exactly how it should be. From what I've tested, the inner dom tree should be there as well.

```js
var Another = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>Just to see if other components are rendered as well</div>
    );
  }
});

var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div id="first"> 
        <div id="sec-1">Hello</div>
        <div id="sec-2">{ this.props.name }</div>
        <Another />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var a = document.createElement('div');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name = "World" /> ,
  a
);

console.log(a.outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

The result in the console is:

```
<div><div data-reactroot="" id="first"><div id="sec-1">Hello</div><div id="sec-2">World</div><div>Just to see if other components are rendered as well</div></div></div>
```

Comment: Opps, I was getting what I'd expect to get! So, is the problem probably `react-mathjax`?

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(c)` at the beginning of `componentToString` function?

Comment: Inserting `console.log(c)` into line 1 of `componentToString` function, I got http://imgur.com/6Q9sjNm (It seems to be a React element.)

Comment: I see from the screenshot you have posted in the question that MathJax inserts a script tag in the DOM which presumably renders the output in the corresponding span. I believe this is the reason you find the span empty when rendering to memory.
If you do need to do it this way, you could make a invisible div in the real DOM (`display: none`) and render your component here. You should get the full content there.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand it... What is the difference between your sample code above and my MathJax case? Why does not your case need to make an invisible div in a real DOM of the page?

Comment: The execution of the `script` tag is done by the browser when this script is present in the DOM. When you render the `MathJax` in memory in `componentToString`, the script tag is inserted but it is not executed as it has not reached the browser's DOM, so the text is not present. In general it is considered a bad practice to have `script` tags inside react components.

Comment: this code does not work anymore, because react behavior is different now and render is not guaranteed to be synchronous. You need to use callback. See https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12227

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using `renderToStaticMarkup` over `renderToString` as it does not add any extra DOM attributes that React uses internally, like `data-reactroot:

```
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from 'react-dom/server'

getString() {
  return renderToStaticMarkup(<AnyComponent />)
}
```

Documentation: