# React how to turn a svgr generated JSX component to an svg string?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg

I am using react functional components generated from svg files by svgr. I am using the standard [Custom Templates](https://react-svgr.com/docs/custom-templates/) and it works great. But I want to somehow extract the actual svg part as a string for some further external processing. How can I do that (I am using using Typescript, by the way) ?

I have modified the svgr template so that it gives me a component which holds the the `${variables.jsx}` part in a distinct constant, but that still is a `JSX.Element`, not a string. And I don't want to do detailed parsing, who knows all the details of svg...

So, I need to turn something like this:

```
const svg: JSX.Element = (<svg> .... yahdah yahdah ... </svg>);
```

into something like this:

```
const str: string = "<svg> ... yahdah yahdah ... </svg>";
```

Some neat javascript magic, maybe ? `.toString()` gives `[ object Object]` or something similarly useless, of course.

Answer (score 0):

colleague of mine found  [this,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47042753)

which leads to something like this:

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
const svg: JSX.Element = (<svg> .... yahdah yahdah ... </svg>);
const str = renderToString(svg);
```

Love it.